# Does it make sense to use Multithreading, Multiprocessing or Concurrent Futures to speed up a process that is basically just iterating

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization, concurrency, multiprocessing

In an endeavour to find the best starting values for a minimisation problem I build something similar following code:

```
def minimize(values):
value1, value2, value3 = values
return (complex_bunch_of_maths)
# (((value1_o_t_c*0.95)*t_i*value1_w_a*value1_coe*value4_w_a*value4_coe)-(value1_cv*0.98))**2+(((value1_o_t_c*0.05)*t_i*value1_w_a*value1_coe*value5_w_a*value5_coe)-(value1_cv*0.02))**2+(((value2_o_t_c*0.95)*t_i*value2_w_a*value2_coe*value4_w_a*value4_coe)-(value2_cv*0.98))**2+(((value2_o_t_c*0.05)*t_i*value2_w_a*value2_coe*value5_w_a*value5_coe)-(value2_cv*0.02))**2+(((value3_o_t_c*0.95)*t_i*value3_w_a*value3_coe*value4_w_a*value4_coe)-(value3_cv*0.98))**2+(((value3_o_t_c*0.05)*t_i*value3_w_a*value3_coe*value5_w_a*value5_coe)-(value3_cv*0.02))**2

def fun():
    for x in range(start,iterations):
        for y in range(start, iterations):
            for z in range(start, iterations):
                res = optimize.minimize(minimize, (x,y,z))
                #If it's the best result so far, keep it, otherwise continue
#Print the best result
```

Would it make sense to instead somehow let every "x" iteration run separately and then make them run "parallel" "threaded" or "concurrent".

I don't know what any of these terms truly mean, but since the runtime of this increases exponentially I want to use all tools at my disposal (that I actually have the skills to implement)

Comment: Yes it can be done and will probably help, but only to a certain point.  This code is O(n^3) and making it concurrent will not change that fact, but depending on how many iterations you have you could get a pretty big speedup.  But since you have no experience with any form of concurrent programming, just be aware it will make your code considerably more complex and bugs can be notoriously difficult to identify.

Comment: Also note, Threads in the _Python_ language in particular are crippled by something called the "Global Interpreter Lock" (a.k.a., "the GIL"). You can't use threads to achieve true parallel execution in a pure Python program. Google for "Python" and "Global Interpreter Lock" to learn what it is, and why it won't be going away any time soon.